# How to use variable name within steps.setup.outputs

Tags: github-actions

I want to use a variable value with in the step variable reference in GitHub Actions.
Is it possible to do so?

Instead of `channelName` hardcoded in `${{steps.setup.outputs.channelName}}` I want to use `${variablename}` which can resolve to anything and use it in `${{steps.setup.outputs.$(variablename)}}`.

I get syntax errors when I am trying to use it.

Comment: Is `${variablename}` in a shell variable? Environment variable?

Comment: Can you show two steps from your workflow maybe?

Comment: Inside `${{ }}` you're already in a JS-ish [expression](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions), where `${}` makes no sense. `steps.setup.outputs[variablename]`, maybe? But without a [mre] it's hard to say if that's even _defined_.

Comment: Yes @jonrsharpe , i did like how you suggested and it worked, THank you all

Answer (score 0):

If you think of `steps.setup.outputs` as a map, then `channelName` is key, I am not quite sure why you want to have your key being dynamic. Note, you can totally control the outputs in the previous steps, and you should already know the keys in subsequent steps.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it by setting the env variable first and referncing it inside the step syntax